# Beamer total number not working and frametitle error

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use a beamer template at [editable](https://www.overleaf.com/3834226516pjqbscdccvxv), however the total frame number returns o. Additionally when I try to uncomment the line that inserts frametitle in the beamerouterthemelsp.sty line 84 an error occurs.

Comment: Hi and welcome! It looks like there's perhaps something outdated or incorrect in this template: to do with `\setcounter{framenumber}{\thelastpagemainpart}`?  If you comment out this line, the total frame number will work properly.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for this. Any clue on how to fix the frametitle issue?

Comment: The `\insertframetitle` command is only available inside the `frametitle` template, so uncommenting line 84 doesn't do what you'd think it would. This is because `\insertframetitle` is not defined inside the `headline` template. Someone who's more knowledgable in Beamer than me may have a recommended way to do this, but simply uncommenting that line will not be enough, it'll require some more changes to the programming of the Lang Sci Press Beamer template itself.